# Import class from another python script

Tags: python

This is `algorithmia_utils.py` file with Class `AlgorithmiaUtils`

```
class AlgorithmiaUtils:

def __init__(self, api_key, username, algo_name, local_dir):
    self.api_key = api_key
    self.username = username
    self.algo_name = algo_name
    self.local_dir = local_dir

    self.algo_namespace = f"{self.username}/{self.algo_name}"
    self.algo_script_path = "{}/{}/src/{}.py".format(
        self.local_dir, algo_name, algo_name
    )
    self.dependency_file_path = "{}/{}/{}".format(
        self.local_dir, algo_name, "requirements.txt"
    )

    self.algo_client = Algorithmia.client(self.api_key)

def upload_model_to_algorithmia(
    self, local_path, algorithmia_data_path, model_name
):
    if not self.algo_client.dir(algorithmia_data_path).exists():
        self.algo_client.dir(algorithmia_data_path).create()
    algorithmia_path = "{}/{}".format(algorithmia_data_path, model_name)
    result = self.algo_client.file(algorithmia_path).putFile(local_path)
```

I want to use the function `upload_model_to_algorithmia` from another script.

Thus, I'm trying:

```
import Algorithmia
import algorithmia_utils as algo_utility
```

And to call the function:

```
algo_utility.AlgorithmiaUtils.upload_model_to_algorithmia(
    local_path = local_path, 
    algorithmia_data_path = algorithmia_data_path, 
    model_name = model_name)
```

Which is returning the error:

```
TypeError: upload_model_to_algorithmia() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Am I supposed to add an additional argument or have I not imported the file correctly, and how to fix this?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

This looks very easy, but so far no solution.

```
import Algorithmia
import algorithmia_utils as algo_utility
from algorithmia_utils import AlgorithmiaUtils as xpto
```

And:

```
xpto.upload_model_to_algorithmia(
    local_path = local_path, 
    algorithmia_data_path = algorithmia_data_path, 
    model_name = model_name)
```

Return the error:

```
TypeError: upload_model_to_algorithmia() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: That's an instance method, not a function. You need an instance of `AlgorithmiaUtils` to call it.

Comment: Ok @chepner but could you elaborate? I'm trying to understand this

Comment: I refer you to the Python tutorial, especially this section on [classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this,

```
from algorithmia_utils import AlgorithmiaUtils
```

First create the class object,

```
algoutil = AlgorithmiaUtils(api_key = api_key, 
    username = username, 
    algo_name = algo_name,
    local_dir = local_dir,)
```

Now you have created an object called `algoutil` which is of the class AlgorithmiaUtils, it has all the methods available to that class.

Then you do this to run your function,

```
algoutil.upload_model_to_algorithmia(local_path = local_path, 
    algorithmia_data_path = algorithmia_data_path, 
    model_name = model_name
)
```

You need to replace the arguments in quotes after the equal signs with the required information.

I think you have gotten code from https://github.com/algorithmiaio/model-deployment/blob/master/xgboost_notebook_to_algorithmia/algorithmia_utils.py but the main service is hosted by algorithmia over here, https://algorithmia.com/developers/clients/python if i am not wrong, you need to go there and make an account and obtain an api key and insert it into the code. For example, it would look something like this,

```
from algorithmia_utils import AlgorithmiaUtils

algoutil = AlgorithmiaUtils(api_key = '8hf81qhg3t8h12f', 
    username = 'unstuck', 
    algo_name = 'algo1',
    local_dir = '/home/docs/whatever',)

algoutil.upload_model_to_algorithmia(local_path = '/home/docs/whatever/algo.csv', 
    algorithmia_data_path = '/path/to/file', 
    model_name = 'model1'
)
```

I have already answered your question on how to create the object and use it, but you need to key in the proper arguments on how to make it work by reading the documentation, this is a different question altogether.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I get the same error

Comment: it says , (upload_model_to_algorithmia() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self, means you did not instantiate it properly

Comment: I get the error: TypeError: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'api_key', 'username', 'algo_name', and 'local_dir' on the algoutil = AlgorithmiaUtils() line

Comment: i cant see your code... you need to include the 4 arguments, 'api_key', 'username', 'algo_name', and 'local_dir', you have only provided, local_path = local_path, 
    algorithmia_data_path = algorithmia_data_path, 
    model_name = model_name

Comment: NameError: name 'api_key' is not defined

Comment: dude.. you have to provide a string which is the api_key... so like api_key = '1ub91gd0g12'

Comment: @unstuck please read my answer again from top to bottom

Comment: Sure, thanks. I did it in a slightly different way and it works.

Comment: @unstuck if my answer helped you, please mark it correct. thanks

Comment: Sure, let me try it

Comment: @unstuck, your answer is not the proper way to import and use a function by the way, you shouldn't import as like that and directly instantiate

Comment: I'm just trying to follow the tutorial that is full of leaks like this one and trying to make some sense, thanks for your help!